# C#. Google Sheets API v4 | Если в массиве данных строки последняя ячейка пустая, то в response возвращается на 1 элемент меньше

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, c#-7.0

> C#. Google Sheets API v4 |

Хелп. Кто разбирается в Google Spredsheets API C# есть вопрос.
Я новичок в программировании, поэтому не судите строго)

В общем, есть  гугл таблица. Состоит из трех столбцов и нескольких строк.
В диапазоне есть пустые ячейки.

Если в таблице ячейка последнего столбца пустая, то этот список на 1 объект меньше.
Т.е. список объектов в response из строки таблицы, где все три заполнены данными, составляет 3 объекта. List("data","data","data")
Если последняя ячейка пустая, то приходит только два объекта List("data","data"). Последнего почему-то нет. Это и странно.
Если последняя заполнена данными, а первая и/или вторая пустые, то возвращается List("","","data")

Вот и вопрос - куда девается пустая ячейка? Уже всю голову себе...

Comment: ну, я не могу сказать точно, но, наверное, это сделано в целях оптимизации, зачем передавать лишние данные о пустых ячейках, если исходную длину вы знаете

Comment: Скорее всего да, только это добавляет сложности, когда в одном ряде много столбцов( Есть сложности с перебором подобных массивов. Спасибо)
Пойду копаться дальше